# Can I change the theme name in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, themes

How can I change the theme name in WordPress and where?

Can I also change the folder name theme1244 in `public/wp-content/themes/theme1244` without having problems in the future?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Step 1: Firstly go to `wp-content/themes/` folder. And then rename your theme folder to whatever you want.

Step 2: Open your theme folder and open `style.css` file. In top part of style.css you will see theme name. Rename it and save changes.

Step 3: Go to `Wp-admin/appearance/themes` and activate your theme under new name.

If you are using child/parent theme and you also rename parent theme folder&name, so  after Step 3 you should additionally change parent theme path (template field) in child theme’s `style.css`.

note : renaming your theme will stop its automatic updates, you should do it manually in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed anserw @Shady

Comment: big *IF*... If you had any customisations like widgets, menus, etc, some plugins (eg, Max Mega Menu widgets), those customizations will be gone, since WP will treat it as a new theme with a blank state to customize. Oh, just noticed [Svetlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960875/279564) mentions how to fix this

Answer (score 24):

All the above is correct, but is not enough. After you rename the theme, e.g. rename the folder `old-theme` --> `new-theme`, you should **copy the theme customizations** (colors, header / footer, widgets, etc.) from the old theme to the new theme. This is done directly in the MySQL database:

1. Find an option named `theme_mods_old-theme` in the table `wp_options`
2. Copy the `option_value` (it is a text holding the theme customizations in a special WordPress format)
3. Put the copied value in a new option named `theme_mods_new-theme` in the `wp_options` table.

[image: Screenshot of the wp_options table in phpMyAdmin]

Comment: Your comment is good, but it is also not enough. For example, if pages are build with elementor builder, it will show them incorrect after theme folder renaming and also this database trick. So there are also some more steps, that by the way i don't know...

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely change the name of the folder without having any problems. If you want to change just the themes name, open the style.css in the root folder of your theme and edit the name in the comments at the top of the file. If you plan on doing more changes, you might be better off creating a child theme: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 2):

I changed my theme name in wp-content/themes/{your site name folder}/style.css
**I am using a child theme**

```
/*
Theme Name: WhateverYouWantToNameIT
Template: twentytwenty 
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are good, but I wanted the full list and this is it
so go to: wp-content/themes/{your site name folder}/style.css
and change this values if they exist, if not you can add them

```
/* this should be at the top of your theme CSS file

 Theme Name:   Twenty Fifteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfifteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twentyfifteenchild
*/
```

[See Source for more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css)

Answer (score -6):

Its absolutely easy and simple, just follow instruction
 1. Just rename theme name with your desire theme name.
 2. open your desire theme name and open style.css file, and find theme name and changes with your desire theme name.
 3. you can see your desire theme in admin dashboard-> appearance-> themes, just select and activate it.

Comment: this answer just repeats [the approved answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36121058/279564)