# After Customizing the Default WordPress theme, Preview button of Post, Page, Products is not working properly

Tags: wordpress

Recently I am facing a strange issue in the WP,

When I customize the default theme (Only changed the theme name twentysixteen to customtheme in folder name and theme name in stylesheet).

Preview button is stop working properly for posts, pages and products.

I even searched each word; either function name, hook name, in comments; changed everything in same way but still no result.

I have tried to search for this issue but didn't find answer to fix it.

Let me know what I am missing while changing the name of theme.

Thanks,

Comment: In theory just changing the folder name and title on the stylesheet should suffice ([Can I change the theme name in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36120925/1287812)). Is there any JavaScript error thrown at the console? If possible, disable all plugins as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply, 
I have tested this in fresh WP install as well, no plugin, and there is no error in console.

Comment: I'd suggest trying another default theme (Twenty *) or downloading it again